Large quantity (surface area) of sealant in stucco after HVAC replacement
I just had my HVAC system replaced by the same company who installed my original system in 2008.
In the areas with open/damaged stucco, I am seeing they used some type of sealant/caulk. I was surprised to see such a large amount used and suspect it will not hold up long term.
Is this method of sealing up stucco durable and resistant to weather and insects? There are obvious gaps ready that I need them to fillin, but I'm wondering if actually need to have this patched in a more durable way.
https://imgur.com/a/J3Sqsfr
https://imgur.com/a/2KhmdrE

why not using stucco to patch up

I don't know! That seems like the logical thing to me... can I just put some over this other goop?

yes you can put stucco over it, just buy some premixed stucco
